# Understanding Feature Grammar syntax

Tags: computational-linguistics, grammar, formal-semantics, feature-structures

Background: I am a software dev who doesn't really know much about linguistics but I am trying to learn some of it for an application I'm making

I am trying to understand Feature Grammar syntax, and I've sorta got it (this is the best tutorial I've found: http://courses.washington.edu/ling471/lab2.html but I have read several others as well)

My main issue is not really understanding where there are certain index values.

http://delph-in.github.io/delphin-viz/demo/#input=%E6%88%91%20%E6%98%AF%20%E4%B8%80%20%E4%B8%AA%20%E5%85%B5&count=1&grammar=zhong-uw&tree=true&mrs=true&dmrs=true

For example, each index value seems to be made up of an alphabetic component, and a numeric component. However I'm not sure exactly what these values are implying, at all.

h0 is presumably the first header handler

But what is e2? x3 (I assume this is a "normal" variable?), i12?

I've looked everywhere for a definition of exactly what these values are. Some of them, such as x3 in the included sample, I can hover over and they highlight a word (or character, in this case), others, such as x8, I hover and they show nothing.

Could someone explain exactly what these index values are and why they're named this way, or point me towards a resource I can read about it? I've been reading about feature grammars for several days now and this concept just isn't clear to me.

From what I've read it sounds like they could be arbitrary, but that still doesn't explain the naming convention. Even if the variable can be named any arbitrary name, there still seems to be a naming convention implying something

Comment: What you are looking at is a specific form of Dependency Grammar. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar. You should pick an example in your native language to start with. That way you can better relate to the data format being used. The example you gave uses syntax specific to the Japanese case. When they say 'Predicate' it means the predicate in a sentence or clause. Study the basic grammar of a clause to begin that's what's being represented. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause .If you look at wiki for clause you'll find the same tree structure that you included in your example.

Comment: From what I understood, OP's question was not about dependency grammar analysis but about the feature grammar one given in the same picture.

Comment: Yes, but the OP also said he's new to linguistics and I was hinting he should make certain to know simple clause grammar.

Comment: In that case, it's probably better to make your post a comment, since it doesn't constitute an actual answer to the question but a hint on further reading.

Comment: Yes, I think @bad_coder 's information is still valuable (and I've saved the links and intend to read them later) though I don't think it's an exact direct answer to what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to understand in detail how the formalism (Minimal Recursion Semantics) works is simply to have a look at the [original paper](http://lingo.stanford.edu/sag/papers/copestake.pdf) by Copestake et.al. You may want to skip the motivation and formal definitions and focus on the representation and the implementation into feature structures/HPSG.
Maybe this [summary](http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/~keberle/Underspecification/Presentations/Handout.pdf) helps for an overview, although it focusses more on the semantic underspecification mechanism and not on the representation in a feature structure.

The naming of the variables follows a specific pattern. Each index is a combination of a letter and a number (continuously numbered; numbering independent between different letters). The letters are abbreviations for certain types (this is already explained in the tutorial you linked to in the answer you gave yourself):

- *x* is an **indivdiual argument** in an **elementary predication (EP)**. An elementary predication consists of a relation symbol with its associated arguments, e.g. `see(x1, x2)` ("x1 sees x2"), where *see* is the relation and *x1* and *x2* are arguments. An individual may be e.g. Peter, or the pen which lies on my desk. A difference is made between scopal and non-scopal arguments.
- *e* stands for for **eventuality**. An eventuality may be the event *see*.
- *i* is a generalization over eventualities and individuals.
- *h* stands for *handle* and is used for handles and labels. A **handle** is a tag which  links up a scopal argument position with the (conjunctions of) EPs that fills it, and a **label** identifies an EP as belonging to a particular tree node. E.g., we could give the EP `see(x1, x2)` the handle `h1`, written `h1: see(x1, x2)` and later reference that EP inside another EP by using its handle; in this usage the handle is called a label.

The actual magic about these variables happens in how they are used together (**coindexation**: If two slots are filled/indexed by the same variale, then this means that the same thing (which is denoted by that variable) fills in both of the roles indicated by the two different slots), and (peculiar to this particular framework, not a universal thing in feature structures) in the equality constraints listed under `HCONS` (**HCONS** = handle constraints; **qeq** = equality modulo quantifiers).

Let's go through the example you linked step by step:
The top handle, i.e. the head of the entire thing is `h0`. The first equality constraint in the `HCONS` list states that `h0` is qeq-equal to `h1`. So the top of the entire sentence that is denoted by the variable `h0` is equal to the thing denoted by the label `h1`. Now what is the thing denoted by `h1`? It's precisely the element which has the value `h1` in its `LBL` (label) feature. This is the relation `是_v_cop⟨2:3⟩`, i.e., via conindexation between the two uses of the variable `h1` together with the equality between the variables `h0` and `h1`, the top of the entire tree is the verb - an observation which matches up with the dependency analysis (the thing with the arrows) given in the lower picture (here, the concepts top/head/root are roughly the same).
The verb, which we briefly reference by its handle `h1`, has three arguments: An eventuality argument `e2`, and two individual arguments `x3` and `x8`. So let's track these variables:
The variable `e2` is used as the index (more precisely:`e2` is the value to the attribute `INDEX` in the feature structure) of the whole thing. The index corresponds to a distinguished normal (non-handle) variable. So the variable for the eventuality which is denoted by the verb serves as the variable for the eventuality denoted by the entire structure, which makes sense because the core meaning of the sentence lies in the event that the verb expresses.
The variable `x3` is also used (coindexed) as the `ARG0` of `pron` and `pronoun_q`. So coindexation of variables tells us that whichever individual is the first argument (presumably the subject) of the verb is the same that is referred to by the ordinary pronoun and the question pronoun (I suppose that's what the abbreviations mean).
A similar reasoning applies to the variable `x8` which is referenced in the relations `card⟨4:5⟩`, `_个_x⟨6:7⟩` and `_兵_n_1⟨8:9⟩` and `exist_q⟨-1:-1⟩`.
Let's now look at the existential quantification, i.e. the relation `exist_q⟨-1:-1⟩`. In the elementary predication *There is a pig which snores* (or *A pig snores* or *Some pig snores*, all treated equivalently), the scopal argument *pig* is the **restriction** and the scopal argument *snore* is the **body** (or **nuclear scope**) of the quantifier *there exists*. In the predication *All happy children laugh*, *happy children* is the restriction and *laugh* the body of the quantifier `all`. The restriction of this particular existential quantifier in use has the label `h14`. This variable serves as a placeholder for whatever is to be inserted as the restriction of the quantication. The handle constraints in `HCONS` tell us that the variable `h14` is quantifier-equal to the relation denoted by the label `h9`. If we now search for this label among the list of relations, we find that it is the handle to the predication `card⟨4:5⟩`. So the predication `card⟨4:5⟩` fills in the role of being the restriction of the existential quantification predication `exist_q⟨-1:-1⟩` .

Unfortunately I don't speak any Chinese so I can't give an explanation with reference to the precise meaning, but I hope you get the idea. **It's pretty much like a paper chase**: You start tracking where else the variable you are interested in is being used, in addition (particular to the MRS framework) follow the path through the equalities that link different variables together, and the semantics of each variable is precisely the combination of places where it is used to fill a particular position in the feature structure. This is the crucial point of coindexation, which is one of the key ideas of feature-based grammars.

Comment: Your answer is way better and more detailed than mine so I am accepting it. Thank you for fleshing everything out.

Comment: Also your first link doesn't work, but I think you mean this paper - http://lingo.stanford.edu/sag/papers/copestake.pdf (I have been studying this paper for most of the day, though I found it a bit hard to follow at times, as I don't have formal training in linguistics)

Comment: Also, I really want to thank you, you made this far more accessible than I've previously seen it written. I've been banging my head on this for the past few days.

Comment: You're welcome; glad I could help.  
Yes, that's the correct paper (I changed the link in my answer to yours). And I agree the paper is not too easy to understand without any prior training - after all, it's an academic formal semantics paper. The best is probably to closely study the examples and try to match what's going on there up with your intuitions about what the single parts of the sentence should mean.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was trying to do (and understanding the variable types was a part of that). Thank you again for your further clarification. It is already looking to be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quote of the syntax for what I was asking about:

http://moin.delph-in.net/ErgSemantics/Basics

> There are three types of variables in MRS, event(ualitie)s (of type e), instances (of type x) and labels or handles (of type h). Of these, the latter serve a formalism-internal role, i.e. assuming a suitable variant of predicate logic as the object language, MRS labels do not map onto logical variables. Eventualities and instances, on the other hand, prototypically correspond to verbal and nominal expressions, respectively. In addition to these most specific variable types, there are underspecifications as follows: i (for individual) is a generalization over eventualities and instances; p (the half-way mark in the alphabet between h and x) is a generalization over labels and instances; and u (for unspecific or maybe unbound) generalizes over all of the above. Note that Copestake et al. (2001) use individual for what is called instance here.